# Remove Numerical Keys from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am simply trying to turn this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20200330
    [1] => 20200329
    [2] => 20200328

)
```

Into this and I am having an extremely hard time

```
Array
(
    20200330,
    0200329,
    20200328,

)
```

Comment: They are the same thing, why do you think you need to remove the keys?

Comment: You already did. An array must have a key

Comment: And for future reference that is not a multi dimentional array its only a single level

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are by default associated with numbers starting from 0

```
<?php
$arr=array("String1","String2","Something else");
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Output will be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "String1"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "String2"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "Something else"
}
```

So if you want to access element of array you type `$arr[index]` and `index` is number by default

Answer (score 0):

All arrays in PHP have a unique key for each value within that array.

By default they are 0, 1, 2, 3, etc unless you explicitly set them (e.g. `$a = ['key' => 1234];`).

It is possible to "remove" keys (set to default without impacting the order) through the use of the `array_values()` function:

```
$a = ['a' => 123, 'b' => 321];
$a = array_values($a);
print_r($a); // [0 => 123, 1 => 321]
```

But it is not possible to entirely remove the keys from an array.

Comment: Thank you. It did seem that way but can't believe there's no way to turn it into a simple, flat array which is what my Javascript accepts.

If I put in an array with keys or indexes, it won't work.

Comment: @BobNichols That's not the case... `echo json_encode(array('asdf', 'ghjk', 'xcvb', 'qwer'));` would yield `["asdf","ghjk","xcvb","qwer"]` - if you properly inspect your JavaScript array you would find it is also numerically indexed as well